# What can open this collar nut?

Tags: tools, socket

The picture is of a device for pressure injection. It is somewhat stuck and I want to open and clean it, so that hopefully it starts to work again. I need to open the collar nut pictured. It has 4 notches that are like half moons. What is the appropriate tool for this? Link to the tool would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what does the user manual say?

Comment: I've seen water filter wrenches that look like they might do the trick.

Comment: Make a C spanner or fully circular spanner.

Comment: What's the overall diameter?  Answers may depend on what tool will fit round it

Comment: Diameter is about 2.5 cm or about an inch.
Don't have user manual.
Can you post the link to such water filter wrenches?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about repairing medical devices are, I suppose, _technically_ withing the realm of DIY, they're not Home Improvement, and, frankly, I don't think we want someone's health potentially resting on our advice.

Answer (score 2):

A "bottom bracket wrench" might do the trick.

[image: Park Tool model HCW-5]
<sup>Image from Park Tool, model HCW-5, as an example</sup>

A "pin wrench" would probably work.

[image: Harbor Freight adjustable pin wrench]
<sup>Image from Harbor Freight - their adjustable pin wrench, as an example</sup>

If you won't want to go buy a tool, just put a flat blade screwdriver against the inside of one of the cutouts and give it a few gentle taps with a hammer. Driving it in the unscrew direction (lefty-loosey, righty-tighty) should loosen it enough that you can then undo it the rest of the way by hand.

Comment: That's great fodder for a whole new question @Bijan79. This is _not_ a general discussion forum, it's a Question & Answer board. I must say, though, that since this is a medical device, it's obvious that someone's health depends on it. I wouldn't ask a bunch of strangers on the internet (no matter how well intentioned) about what kind of grease to use. I'd contact the mfgr & ask them. You may pay more for it, but you'll have the security of knowing it's the right thing and is _not_ going to cause more harm than good.

Comment: None of us know the age or condition of this device, how critical some corrosion on the spring might be, how "strong" a replacement spring should be. I'm all for DIYing things, but I would not say "calling it a fix" is sufficient when talking about _someone else's_ medical device. Get it repaired properly or at least get expert input from the mfgr.

Answer (score 0):

**Strap wrench?**

[image: Strap wrench?]

Rubber strap will not mar smooth metal.  Circumferentially grippy.  Not too expensive if it turns out to not work.